# Jquery animation loop problem

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to execute an animation function in a loop. I have manged to figure out one iteration of it but i am unable to figure out how to repeat the loop a set number of time. Below is my animation function. Please help me figure out how do i run this any number of times or even make it a never ending loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var delay = 150;
    var times = 4;
    var i = 1;

    doMove = function() {
        if( i < times ){
            $('#lip').removeClass('lip'+i);
            $('#lip').addClass('lip'+(i+1));
        } else if ( i == times ) {
            $('#lip').removeClass('lip4');
            $('#lip').addClass('lip1');
        }

        ++i;
        if( i >= times ) {
            clearInterval( interval ) ;
        }
    }

    var interval = setInterval ( "doMove()", delay );


});
</script>
```

Thanks a lot. I am new to jquery.

Comment: `var interval = setInterval ( doMove, delay );`

Comment: it's [working](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/k8Ueg/) what is exactly your problem?

Comment: In "user" terms, what does changing the class from lip1 to lip2 to lip3 and so on actually do - is it changing a background image or size or colour or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is very short in your script - so perhaps you are not seeing the changes take place. Try changing

```
var delay = 150;
```

To

```
var delay = 1000; // 1 second
```

**UPDATE**

Ah - you want it to run again on completion... here is an example:

repeats = 0 will be infinite loops, 1 will run once, 2 will run twice and so on...

```
var delay = 150;
var times = 4;
var repeats = 3;
var i = 1;
var j = 0;

doMove = function() {
    if( i < times ){
        $('#lip').removeClass('lip'+i);
        $('#lip').addClass('lip'+(i+1));
    } else if ( i == times ) {
        $('#lip').removeClass('lip4');
        $('#lip').addClass('lip1');
    }

    ++i;
    if( i >= times ) {
        if (j < repeats || repeats == 0) {
            i = 1;
        } else {
            clearInterval( interval ) ;
        }
    }
    ++j;
}

var interval = setInterval ( "doMove()", delay );
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Although there will be a j++; with i=1; 

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can pass your function directly to setInterval() instead of using a String and a global function.

Comment: @Vincent Robert - yes @Reigel mentions this in comments above also - it avoids the eval of the string, which is nicer.

Comment: And more importantly, "doMore" can be a local variable and not pollute the global scope

Comment: @Vincent Robert - I think that's going a long way beyond the scope of the original question.